# Stop page from loading after command executed

Tags: firefox, imacros

Is it possible to have an imacros script force firefox to STOP loading a page after it executed the previous command.

```
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:flg-addSpray ATTR=NAME:Submit
WAIT SECONDS = 10
[Stop Page Load]
[Next Commands]
```

For whatever reason, sometimes my script gets stuck after the submit button is executed, it never properly loads the next page, or gets stuck on the next page. And script halts not moving along with a long string of commands.

It's in a loading infinite loop. I want it to STOP. And move on.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just should use the built-in variable [`!TIMEOUT_PAGE`](http://wiki.imacros.net/!TIMEOUT_PAGE):

```
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 15
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:flg-addSpray ATTR=NAME:Submit
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 60
WAIT SECONDS = 10
```

Comment: You placed the same tag before and after the submit button, Why?

Comment: So that your macro doesn't get stuck for more than 15 seconds.